# Usar HTML em PHP

Tags: php, html

Tenho o seguinte código que não está funcionando.

```
echo "<a href='memberarea.html'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Member area</a>";
```

Eu creio que não estou fazendo bem a incorporação do HTML em PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa escapar as aspas ou trocá-las por aspas simples, já que você está usando aspas para o echo.

Escapando as aspas:

```
echo "<a href='memberarea.html'><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-lock\"></span> Member area</a>";
```

Ou:

```
echo "<a href='memberarea.html'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-lock'></span> Member area</a>";
```

Comment: Gosto dessa versatilidade do PHP podendo usar qualquer dos dois tipos Duplas ou Simples, mas existe uma diferença entre elas, as Aspas Simples compreendem a string como literal, Exemplo: echo('Meu $texto'); irá imprimir a string literal "Meu $texto", e echo("Meu $texto"); irá imprimir o conteúdo da variável, eu sempre uso aspas duplas assim não preciso quebrar a string ou usar escapes, mas quando tenho que usar html dentro do php uso aspas simples, Exemplo: echo("Ola  $mundo"); e echo('<a href="url">link</a>'); perceba que no segundo echo não precisei de escape deixando o código mais "limpo".

Answer (score 1):

Se usas aspas duplas para defenir a string, tens de usar aspas simples no meio ou escapá-las:

```
echo "algo \"algo dentro de aspas\" algo";
```

ou

```
echo "algo 'algo dentro de aspas' algo";
```

No teu caso poderia ser:

```
echo "<a href='memberarea.html'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-lock'></span> Member area</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Realmente, o código apresentado não tem necessidade de ser escrito em php, pode ser escrito em html mesmo:

```
<a href='memberarea.html'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Member area</a>
```

Mas caso queira colocar o php, você deverá dentro de um arquivo .php fazer uso de:

```
-- script html aqui
<?php
    -- codigo php aqui
?>
-- continuação do script html
```

Comment: De fato, sempre que possível a ideia é separar HTML do PHP, e eu gosto disso, porém a casos em que precisamos colocar o HTML dentro do PHP, por exemplo quando usa Templates separando totalmente o HTML do PHP, lá no PHP as vezes precisa fazer um complemento de HTML para ser exibido num container do Template, ai eu faço muito uso de aspas simples, exemplo: echo('<table class="myclass"><tr><td>'.$texto.'</td><.tr></table>'); Evitando assim aquele monte de barras \ que fica complicado de sabem onde começa e onde termina o html